# How to extract year from a date string?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark 2.1.2.

I'm working with datetime data, and would like to get the year from a `dt` string using spark sql functions.

The code I use is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().
appName("myapp").master("local").getOrCreate()

case class Person(id: Int, date: String)
import spark.implicits._

val mydf: DataFrame = Seq(Person(1,"9/16/13")).toDF()
val select_df: DataFrame = mydf.select(unix_timestamp(mydf("date"),"MM/dd/yy").cast(TimestampType))
select_df.select(year($"date")).show()
```

I expect the year of the date as `13` in the example above.

**Actual**: *org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`date`' given input columns: [CAST(unix_timestamp(date, MM/dd/yy) AS TIMESTAMP)];;
'Project [year('date) AS year(date)#11]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case class Person(id: Int, date: String)
val mydf = Seq(Person(1,"9/16/13")).toDF
val solution = mydf.withColumn("year", year(to_timestamp($"date", "MM/dd/yy")))
scala> solution.show
+---+-------+----+
| id|   date|year|
+---+-------+----+
|  1|9/16/13|2013|
+---+-------+----+
```

It looks like `year` does not give you two digits but four for years. I'm leaving the string truncation as a home exercise for you :)

---

> Actual: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'date' given input columns: [CAST(unix_timestamp(date, MM/dd/yy) AS TIMESTAMP)];; 'Project [year('date) AS year(date)#11]

The reason of the exception is that you want to access the "old" `date` column (in `select(year($"date"))`) that's no longer available after `select` (`select(unix_timestamp(mydf("date"),"MM/dd/yy").cast(TimestampType))`.

You could use `alias` or `as` to change the weird-looking auto-generated name into something else like `date` again, and that would work.

Comment: sorry one more quick question, let's say i also have a time column.When I select the concatenation of the date and the time column from the df and show there is no error do u know why?

Comment: I need more information. I always thought that _"there is no error"_ is good. If you have a question, please ask another question on SO. Leave a link here. Thanks. If my answer to your question about date conversion worked, please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Even though it seems like they should have the same result.

Comment: Here take a look at the new question if u can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136529/combining-two-columns-casting-two-timestamp-and-selecting-from-df-causes-no-err