# Combining two columns, casting two timestamp and selecting from df causes no error, but casting one column to timestamp and selecting causes error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

## Description

When I try to select a column that is cast to unix_timestamp and then timestamp from a dataframe there is a sparkanalysisexception error. **See link below.**

However, when I combine two columns, and then cast the combo to a unix_timestamp and then timestamp type and then select from a df there is no error.

## Disparate Cases

Error:
[How to extract year from a date string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100885/how-to-extract-year-from-a-date-string)

No Error

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().
  appName("myapp").master("local").getOrCreate()

case class Person(id: Int, date: String, time:String)
import spark.implicits._

val mydf: DataFrame = Seq(Person(1,"9/16/13", "11:11:11")).toDF()
//solution.show()
//column modificaton

val datecol: Column = mydf("date")
val timecol: Column = mydf("time")
val newcol: Column = unix_timestamp(concat(datecol,lit(" "),timecol),"MM/dd/yy").cast(TimestampType)

mydf.select(newcol).show()
```

## Results

**Expected**: 
Error-sparkanalysis, can't find unix_timestamp(concat(....)) in mydf

**Actual**:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CAST(unix_timestamp(concat(date,  , time), MM/dd/yy) AS TIMESTAMP)|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                              2013-09-16 00:00:...|
```

Answer (score 0):

These do not seem disparate cases. In the erroneous case, you had a new dataframe with changed column names. See below :-

```
val select_df: DataFrame = mydf.select(unix_timestamp(mydf("date"),"MM/dd/yy").cast(TimestampType))
select_df.select(year($"date")).show()
```

Here, `select_df` dataframe has changed column names from `date` to something like `cast(unix_timestamp(mydf("date"),"MM/dd/yy")) as Timestamp`

While in the case mentioned above, you are just defining a new column when you say :-

```
val newcol: Column = unix_timestamp(concat(datecol,lit(" "),timecol),"MM/dd/yy").cast(TimestampType)
```

And then you use this to select from your dataframe and thus it gives out expected results.

Hope this makes things clearer.